# Deleted entry (soft deleted) and unique validator

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, symfony-2.8

I am working on user management where users are deleted (soft). It seems if an entry is "soft deleted" the validator is ignored resulting in a error/exception being executed due to unique constraint violation. Steps to reproduce would be:

1. Create a user entry with email "test@test.com"
2. Delete entry (soft delete)
3. Create a new entry with "test@test.com" again and it will throw an error with unique constraint violation.

I want to display the error like "This email was previously used and deleted, please choose other".

Is there a way to detect that user was previously deleted during form validation (not after)?

Comment: You should use a [custom repository method](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#repositorymethod) in order to verify your unique criteria

Answer (score 0):

since it's a soft delete you can always do a select query check to see if the user is already deleted or not